# How to remove white space in html using Tritium

Tags: moovweb

I'm using the [Moovweb SDK](http://www.moovweb.com/developers/moovwebsdk) and I'd like to remove excess white space from the beginning or end of any elements.  It sometimes shows up as
               or 
and I want to remove it since it messes with my spacing.  How can I get around doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex to replace the leading and tailing whitespace with nothing.

Inside a tag, you can open up a text scope and use the `replace(...)` function to replace leading and trailing whitespace:

```
text() {
    replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, "")
}
```

Here's a working example in play.tritium.io:

http://play.tritium.io/648c6b2f72266b7b7db308e14dcb85f71707f4ee

Comment: that solves the problem!
To remove all extra/unnecessary space it's easy to, adding `|(\s)\s+`, like this: `replace(/^\s+|\s+$|(\s)\s+/, "$1")`. Note the extra `$1` that reflects `(\s)` so we don't end with zero spaces in between words.

Answer (score 0):

```
text("   I'm an example             ")
text() {
  trim()
}
```

can also be used to remove white spaces